# Dr Memory with Premake5 : How to specify Debug Information

Tags: visual-studio, premake, dr-memory

I want to use Dr. Memory on my Visual Studio 2019 project.

Dr. Memory has a page on how to prepare your application properly to use Dr. Memory: http://drmemory.org/docs/page_prep.html

I know how to disable inlining and turn off frame pointer optimizations.

```lua
omitframepointer("On")
inlining("Disabled")
symbols("On")
```

But I'm stuck as to how to generate the debug information that Dr. Memory wants.

I have tried adding this to my premake script

```lua
linkoptions { "/DEBUG:FULL" }
```

But when I add this to my solution all I end up with is this error message:
2>LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/DEBUG:FULL'; ignored

But if I type in /DEBUG:FULL manually (under aditional options) into visual studio it works.

So I guess I have 2 questions:

Who does this linkoptions command not work?
Is there an alternative I can use to achieve the same goal?

Answer (score 1):

you can try with

```
symbols 'On'
```

https://github.com/premake/premake-core/wiki/symbols

I think debug:full might be a compiler option not a linker option as debug information is generated at compile time. at link time the inofrmation should just be gathered from obj files and put in a pdb file (when using full).

Comment: I forgot to mention that I did also have symbols 'on'

Also when I typed in /DEBUG:FULL manually into visual studio it was in Configuration Properties->Linker->Command Line->Additional Options. Doesn't that make it a linker option?